# set only one trigger using timeBased method in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm currently working on adding a time-based trigger to my function. Basically, my function (called mainFunction) fetches email from a Gmail account and displays its body to a spreadsheet. I want to make the function called every 5 min, so I wrote

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("mainFunction")
 .timeBased()
 .everyMinutes(5)
 .create();
```

and ran my function.

My function works fine and I can see the data on my spreadsheet. However, after I ran the function and waited more than 5 min, then when I check my triggers section in the apps script, I see there are tons of triggers displayed, like the image below.
[triggers on apps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHunE.png)

I think the problem here is I set and create a new trigger, which runs my 'mainFunction', every 5 minutes, so that is why I see tons of triggers on my apps script triggers section. Am I right? If I create the new trigger every 5 minutes, which I'm not supposed to, where should I change in order to just run the function every 5 minutes (not create a new function)?

Answer (score 2):

### Issue:

The most probable issue is that you have declared this code:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("mainFunction")
 .timeBased()
 .everyMinutes(5)
 .create();
```

either **outside** of every function in your script (global decleration) or **inside** `mainFunction` and this is why it is being executed every five minutes. But most likely, you have declared it inside `mainFunction`.

### Solution:

Delete all current triggers of the project (or at least the triggers for `mainFunction`). You can do that manually (from the current project's triggers) or [programatically](http://var%20triggers%20=%20ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();%20%20for%20(var%20i%20=%200;%20i%20%3C%20triggers.length;%20i++)%20%7B%20%20%20%20ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers%5Bi%5D);%20%20%7D).

After all the triggers are deleted then make sure to **separate** the trigger creation code from `mainFunction`. Manually execute **ONLY** and **ONCE** the `createTrigger` function:

```
function mainFunction(){

  // code to be triggered every 5 minutes

}

function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("mainFunction")
 .timeBased()
 .everyMinutes(5)
 .create();
}
```

[image]

and then you will see only one trigger in the project's trigger menu which will be responsible for triggering `mainFunction` every five minutes.